# Why the ringtone uri returned by RingtoneManager fails when being set as data source for a Media Player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to set the data source for Anndroid Media Player. I am using the following code.

```
Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
// alarm_uri = null

if (alarmUri == null) {
   alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

  // alarm_uri = "content://settings/system/notification_sound"
}

alarmMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
alarmMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alarmUri);
```

While setting data source, it throws the following error:

"setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000"

When I test the same code on another phone, I get the value "content://media/internal/audio/media/44" for alarm_uri. I feel something wrong with the phone which is creating the problem.

Can someone tell what could be the issue?

Comment: please try - alarmMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), alarmUri);

Comment: @pskink I have provided the value in comment line i.e. // alarm_uri = "content://settings/system/notification_sound"

Comment: @pskink I will try tomorrow. That device is not with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION` and `RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM`were returning invalid value as the URI because alarm and notification were set as none in the device. Once it was set to specific value, it started returning meaningful value.